# is there a way to convert one column into many based on the categories in python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset that has details of interaction in an e-learning platform

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [01, 01, 01, 02, 02, 03,03], 
                   'activity_type': ['resource', 'url', 'homepage', 'url','homepage','resource','url'],
                   'sum_click': [23,15,2,25,2,16,2],
                   'course':['math', 'physics','math', 'math','physics','math','math'],
                   'final_result'=['pass', 'pass', 'pass','pass','fail','pass','pass'],
})
```

which will look like this

| id | activity_type | sum_click | course | final_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | resource | 23 | math | pass |
| 1 | url | 15 | physics | pass |
| 1 | homepage | 2 | math | pass |
| 2 | url | 25 | math | pass |
| 2 | homepage | 2 | physics | fail |
| 3 | resource | 16 | math | pass |
| 3 | url | 2 | math | pass |

I want the dataset to transform into this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [01, 01, 02, 02, 03], 
                   'type_resource': [23,0,0,0,16],
                   'type_url': [0,15,25,0,2],
                   'type_homepage':[2,0,0,2,0]
                   'course':['math', 'physics','math','physics','math'],
                   'final_result'=['pass', 'pass', 'pass','fail','pass'],
})
```

| id | type_resource | type_url | type_homepage | course | final_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 0 | 2 | math | pass |
| 1 | 0 | 15 | 0 | physics | pass |
| 2 | 0 | 25 | 0 | math | pass |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | physics | fail |
| 3 | 16 | 2 | 0 | math | pass |

is there anyway to transform the dataset in pandas?

Comment: `df.pivot(index=['id', 'course', 'final_result'], columns='activity_type', values='sum_click').reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks @mozway! this worked. The values were wrong initially but I added `aggfunc = 'sum'` to the code and it worked fine :)